# How to bind a list of a class that includs a dictionary to the view in asp.net core?

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have a class that includes one dictionary<int,string>.
int is the key of radio button and value is the choice title.
I'm trying to get a list of dictionaries in controller includes keys and values of radio buttons.
when I run the program the list is 0. I think there is something wrong with the name of the radio buttons and input for choice title but I don't know what should I write.

```
public class ChoiceQuestion
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> Choice { get; set; }
    public int Answer { get; set; }    
}
```

in the controller I have this:

```
 public IActionResult CreateQuestion(int courseId, List<ChoiceQuestion> choices,
        QuestionType type, Question question)
    {
        _questionService.AddQuestion(courseId, type, choices, question);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
 <div class="form-group choiceDiv" style="display: none;" id="choiceDiv">
            <a id="plus"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <input type="radio" name="choices.choice[0].key" value="1" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices.choice[0].value" />

            <input type="radio" name="choices.choice[1].key" value="1" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices.choice[1].value" />

            <span asp-validation-for="Choice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you want to pass data to `List<ChoiceQuestion> choices`,so your name of input need to be `choices[xxx].choice[xxx]`.

And then,you can change your text type inputs name before form submitting,so that text type inputs' value will be binded to dictionary of `List<ChoiceQuestion> choices`.
Here is a working demo:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
    <div class="form-group choiceDiv" style="display: none;" id="choiceDiv">
        <a id="plus"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
        <input type="radio" name="choices[0].choice[0].key" value="1" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices[0].choice[key]" value="choicetitle1" />

        <input type="radio" name="choices[0].choice[1].key" value="2" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices[0].choice[key]" value="choicetitle2" />

        <span asp-validation-for="Choice" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        var keys = [];
        var count = 0;
        $("#choiceDiv input[type='radio']").each(function () {
            keys.push($(this).val());
        });
        $("#choiceDiv input[type='text']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace("key", keys[count]));
            count++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I change text type input names to `choices[0].choice[key]`,and before form submitting,I replace 'key' in name to the value of radio button.And then form will post dictionary data.

result:
[image]

Or you can remove radio buttons,and use view like the following:

```
<div class="form-group choiceDiv" style="display: none;" id="choiceDiv">
            <a id="plus"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
            <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices[0].choice[1]" value="choicetitle1"/>

            <input type="text" placeholder="گزینه " name="choices[0].choice[2]" value="choicetitle2"/>

            <span asp-validation-for="Choice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

And then you will get key=1,value="choicetitle1";key=2,value="choicetitle2" in dictionary.